# Tool for measuring entropy quality?

Tags: random, linux

Is there a tool available for Linux systems that can measure the "quality" of entropy on the system?

I know how to count the entropy:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

And I know that some systems have "good" sources of entropy (hardware entropy keys), and some don't (virtual machines).

But is there a tool that can provide a metric as to the "quality" of the entropy on the system?

Comment: Im interested, Why would you want to calculate entropy of a system?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/ works for me.

```
sudo apt-get install ent
head -c 1M /dev/urandom > /tmp/out
ent /tmp/out
```

Comment: Cool tool. You can check a device in just one command with `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=1 | ent`

Comment: Note that running an entropy estimator on `/dev/urandom` is completely useless. `/dev/urandom` is the output of a crypto-quality PRNG, and an entropy estimator will always give full marks to any semi-decent PRNG. **You need to run the entropy estimator on the unconditioned entropy source**, which Linux doesn't expose outside the kernel. Cc @DustinKirkland

Comment: @Gilles there is no way?

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli No way to do what? Estimate the entropy from the output of `/dev/urandom`? Yes. The output of `/dev/urandom` (or `/dev/random`, same issue) is the output of a crypto-quality PRNG, and that will always have top marks for entropy estimation. If you want to estimate the entropy, you need to dig into the kernel, figure out what it uses for entropy sources, and measure for a VERY long time.

Comment: @Gilles I guess the raw entropy source affects the final quality of the PRNG, or am I wrong? I am using a TL100 to feed the entropy pool. Thank you.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli No, the entropy source does not affect the PRNG in a way that can be measured. This is rather off-topic for [unix.se] but I know I've seen it discussed on [crypto.se], try searching the tags [entropy] and [randomness] there.

Answer (score 7):

"ent" is an excellent command line tool for a simple and quick estimation of entropy.

I've used it to help learn how linear congruential generators work. But if by "measuring entropy" you mean "measuring randomness"... the problem becomes more complex.

For a more robust test of randomness you should checkout the dieharder test suite:
http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php

It is not as easy to use as "ent" but it is far more rigorous.

For more in depth study, "Cipher's by Ritter" also provides a good selection of links:

http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/NETLINKS.HTM#RandomnessLinks

Answer (score 3):

Tools can only ever give you an upper bound on the entropy. For most uses, in particular security related uses you're more interested in a lower bound.

Calculating the entropy of an arbitrary file is mathematically impossible, so there can be no tool that can do it.

I can easily write a file generator that generates very low entropy files, but will still pass your entropy tests. Just use a crypto PRNG with a small seed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Binwalk with the `-E` option:

```
# binwalk -E data

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     ENTROPY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Falling entropy edge (0.000000)
2443264       0x254800        Rising entropy edge (0.988510)
```

You can get the source code from [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk).

Answer (score 0):

[ncomputers.org/entropyarray](https://ncomputers.org/entropyarray) performs a faster entropy test than `ent` with 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 and 512 bits serial correlation tests.

with [ncomputers.org/entropy](https://ncomputers.org/entropy) tool, you may also perform visual frequency and distribution tests, plotting the outputs **entropy.freq** and **entropy.gaus**

as an example you may perform an online test of up to 1GB using [servertest.online/entropytest](https://servertest.online/entropy)

[image: entropy.freq]
[image: entropy.gaus]

Answer (score -5):

I think you are looking for:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm well aware of entropy_avail.  I'm trying to measure the quality of that entropy.