# Zip does not compress files when zipping

Tags: zip, compression

I have zipped a file recursively in a directory. But what I notice with these last few zips is that the files do not get compressed.

```
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042406.dcm (deflated 0%)
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042279.dcm (deflated 0%)
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042466.dcm (deflated 0%)
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042200.dcm (deflated 0%)
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042227.dcm (deflated 0%)
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042372.dcm (deflated 0%)
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042245.dcm (deflated 0%)
  adding: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.64517.30000014091005511462300042282.dcm (deflated 0%)
```

Can anyone explain why this would occur when using zip?

Comment: There are several reasons for the zip to not compress as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309012/zip-deflated-0-why-no-compression).

Comment: Thanks, one thing in that link stood out that may explain the reasoning when I am zipping files at work. And it makes plenty of sense since the files are encrypted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155069/zip-does-not-compress-files-when-zipping#comment253504_155069), the SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309012/zip-deflated-0-why-no-compression) had this pretty much covered. Now, I wanted to experiment on how this deflation actually works. So, I did the below testing.

*What is Entropy?*

**Entropy** is a measure of the unpredictability of an information stream. A perfectly consistent stream of bits (all zeroes, or all ones) is totally predictable (has no entropy). A stream of completely unpredictable bits has maximum entropy. The idea of entropy of information is credited to Claude Shannon who gave a formula to express it.

Now, I created a file just with `y` or `n` as below.

```
perl -e 'my $y; $y .= int(rand(100))>90 ? "y" : "n" for (0..999); print $y;' > f1
```

Now, I ran the command, `zip f1.zip f1` and got the output as,

```
zip f1.zip f1
  adding: f1 (deflated 89%)
```

Now, in the above command we have predictable bytes `y` or `n` which is why we have a deflated percentage of 89.

Now, I am carrying out the experiment as below.

```
 dd if=/dev/urandom of=./f2 bs=1M count=1
```

If I do the command `zip f2.zip f2`, this is what I got as output.

```
zip f2.zip f2
  adding: f2 (deflated 0%)
```

Since, the `/dev/urandom` is completely unpredictable, we are getting an deflation rate of 0%. The reference link that I have provided below has very good explanation on how to calculate entropy for predictable bytes.

Also, there is this tool `ent` to calculate a file's entropy in debian based systems. You could just do an `apt get install ent` and calculate the entropy rate as `ent filename` and figure out what's really happening.

You could read from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31789/47538) about this command.

**References**

http://troydhanson.github.io/misc/Entropy.html

Comment: The tool sounds interesting enough but I am not working on a debian based system. I am using an rpm based.

Comment: @ryekayo, yeah me too. I tried installing but it is not there. Moreover, as far as I read, the tool can give just give some upper bound and it won't be a correct calculation.

Comment: That's okay. I just needed a brief explanation of what I was seeing because at my job we do a lot of zipping and file transfers and I notice every so often that some files would not compress when zipping and it puzzled me

Comment: Another thing you cannot compress by zipping: A file that has already been compressed. Its redundancy has already been squeezed out.

Comment: entropy is a property of data _generation method_, not the specific produced bytes.